# issue with displaying on git-bash windows 7

Tags: windows, git, screen, display

i just installed the last version of git (2.8.1)  for windows7 from  the official site, but when i run  git-bash and type somme commands in the cmd,  the screen doesn't updated correctly when i delete somme chars from the line command. in contrary when i click the (del)'s key a space char is added to the display instead of deleting the chars from the screen.

---

for example :

***cd /d/formationss***

if i want delete the two last 's' of 'formationss' with the (del) key of keyboard , what i see is :

***cd /d/formationss__***

instead of deleting the two 's'  space's chars are added. 
but things work perfectly on background, the delete command is work the problem concern only the displaying issue .

---

i tried to reinstall the software but still doesn't work.

i well be grateful for your help, thank you for your time and consideration and so sorry for my bad english